# How can I make a row of 6 images in bootstrap cols reposition themselves based on screen size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

Bootstrap newbie here,

I have a row of 6 images in a single row. Upon resizing the screen I would like them to either move down to 2 rows of 3, or 3 rows of 2 etc based on the size of the screen.

As far as I understand, there is a way to do this with bootstrap?

Here is what I have so far:
A single row class
A loop iterating through all the images stored in a particular folder adding images into a col-md-2 class

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `col-lg-*`, `col-md-*`, `col-sm-*` and `col-xs-*`, not just `col-md-*`. Check the documentation for the range for each of them. Add please add your codes for visuals

Comment: Can you post the code you have now in the question? Have you read the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use col-sm and col-xs as you you col-md-2 to specify a different display based on size.

Example :

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6">image</div>
```

In this example in middle screen your div will take 2 columns and in extra small it will take 6 columns.

Look bootstrap doc to see size corresponding and to get each size available

Answer (score 1):

Try this **Markup** .....

```css
figure img {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <figure>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/zQIlCOu.jpg" alt="image">
        <figcaption>

        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <figure>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/zQIlCOu.jpg" alt="image">
        <figcaption>

        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <figure>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/zQIlCOu.jpg" alt="image">
        <figcaption>

        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <figure>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/zQIlCOu.jpg" alt="image">
        <figcaption>

        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <figure>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/zQIlCOu.jpg" alt="image">
        <figcaption>

        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <figure>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/zQIlCOu.jpg" alt="image">
        <figcaption>

        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>





  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I ended up going with col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-2. thanks for the tip!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tiaan